# Creating dotfiles for iTerm.app and Terminal.app — how to detect 256 color support?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, colors, xterm

I’m creating custom dotfiles (`.bash_profile` and the like) for use with OS X’s Terminal.app and iTerm.app.

I’d like to configure some settings conditionally, based on whether the active application supports 256 colors or not. (iTerm.app supports it, but Terminal.app doesn’t.) This would be possible using an `if` statement (pseudo-code):

```
if 256_COLOR_SUPPORT; then
  # Make use of all available colors (iTerm.app)
else
  # Fall back to 16-color mode (Terminal.app)
fi
```

The problem is I don’t know how to write the condition for the `if` statement.

Hence my question: is it possible to detect 256 color support? If so, how?

---

**Update:** I found out how to detect which terminal application I’m currently in:

iTerm.app:

```
$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM
iTerm.app
```

Terminal.app:

```
$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM
Apple_Terminal
```

So for now, I’m using the following check:

```
if [ $TERM_PROGRAM == "iTerm.app" ]; then
  # Groovy 256-color stuff
fi
```

I’d still like to know if it’s possible to detect the number of available colors in the active application though. I tried `tput colors` but that seems useless since Terminal.app lies and returns `256`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done via the TERM variable. Normally it would be set to "xterm", but in a 256-color terminal you can set it to "xterm-256color". The terminfo database has an appropriate entry for that, and many programs automatically switch to 256-color mode when they see "xterm-256color".

(Does Terminal.app really not have 256 color support?)

Comment: The problem is `$TERM` can be set to `xterm-256color` in Terminal.app as well, so this technique is not very robust. And no, Terminal.app really doesn’t support 256 colors, sadly. Try using 256 colors in Terminal.app and you’ll see stuff flickering all over your screen :( Maybe in OS X 10.7 Lion…

Comment: The default values for `$TERM` seem to be these: `xterm` for iTerm.app, and `xterm-color` for Terminal.app. I’m not sure how reliable this is, but I suppose that could be used to detect which terminal is active. I’m not sure if it would be better than using `$TERM_PROGRAM` though. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The TERM_PROGRAM variable appears to be specific to Mac terminals, but as long as that's all you need the dotfiles for, I guess that's fine. The TERM variable, meanwhile, is standard across systems and terminals, and setting it appropriately tells programs (via terminfo) what to expect from your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the a bit of the same issue I think, and the way btw to force terminal.app into 8 bit is to go to the:

1. Preferences;
2. Settings;
3. Pick color scheme;
4. Advanced tab.
5. Then set "declare terminal as" to xterm-color instead of `xterm-256color`

Answer (score 0):

`tput colors` returns the number of colous the current terminal type supports:

```
matt@dell:~$ tput colors
8
```

So you can capture that into a variable:

```
COLORS=$(tput colors)
```

and compare that variable with known / expected values

```
if [ $COLORS -eq 256 ]; then
   ... do your 256 colour stuff
else
   ... just 16 or 8 colours (16 is 8 colours in normal and bright mode)
fi
```

***Update***

Your update happened while I was writing that answer.

You should force Terminal.app to use an 8 colour terminal type (not sure how)

Comment: That depends on TERM being set appropriately in the first place. Otherwise, as long as TERM==xterm, `tput colors` will yield 8.

Comment: Indeed, and so, it is not relevant. I never changed iTerm settings about colors support and when I echo `TERM`, it displays me `xterm`. So the information is not reliable concerning the functionality. Since then, is there another way to find out if term supports 256 colors?